# Sql statement order by with condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

this myTable show all row with `order by no asc`,

[image]

My question is, I want to show all row with custom `order by`,
in part of first rows are which have the same data as the current date (*use 2015-09-18 as current date*), after that please custom the rows based on the smallest number, so the result after custom `order by` will become sort from  5,4,1,2,3.

how i achive that with sql statement ? thank.

Comment: You can use CASE expressions in the ORDER BY.

Comment: So the order is: 1. current date first then all other dates. 2. within current date order by time ascending ("no" doesn't matter here) 3. within other dates order by "no" descending (date/time doesn't matter here). Yes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN date(date) = curdate() THEN no * (-1) -- when date is current date, sort descending (ascending by negative ID, to reverse order)
        ELSE no -- else keep default ascending sort order
    END
```

Comment: sorry, this sql work properly,but i have some question, still based question above, i want to sort become 4,5,1,2,3. how i achieve that?

Comment: order by 2 things:
case when date(date) = curdate() then 1 else 0 end desc, no desc

Comment: ok, this my last question, i promise, I want to sort desc current date till 7days ago after that sort 'no' asc, so the result will become 4,5,2,1,3? hope you not bored. :)

Comment: same deal, just sort by a case condition. As in the answer, but replace "date(date) = curdate()" with "date(date) > curdate() - interval 7 day"

Comment: and no worries, Stack is for asking - but also take care to learn the principles behind the answers, so if you understand them, you won't need to depend on how fast a question is answered ;)